dotnet, End of Third-party cookies & localhost
With the end of thrid-party cookies now upon us, I have a problem with authenticating when running my web app at localhost.
We have an auth server running in a seperate app. When the client is at localhost, the auth server is on a different domain, therefore the auth cookies are third party. This means I get continually logged out.
Is it possible to run my client from dotnet.exe, running at our domain (e.g. by configuring launchSettings) rather than localhost?
The best solution I have so far is to extend the timeout of the auth token so that the third-party cookie doesn't come in to play.
Is there another way of avoiding third-party cookie blocking while running at localhost?

If your domain is mydomain.com, can you define a hostname like client.mydomain.com pointing to 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts (\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts on Windows)?

Thanks, but how does dotnet know to use that domain?  My localhost app is running on a specifc port (e.g. localhost:8888), so I need a way of binding that port to that domain.  I already have lots of domains pointing to 127.0.0.1 in my hosts file (on Windows), which I use with IIS bindings.

Bear in mind that client.mydomain.com != client.mydomain.com:8888 - these are different domains and will still fall foul of third-party cookie blocking.

The port is not considered when determining the same-site condition.

On further investigation, it should be possible to set up a reverse proxy using URL rewriting, rewriting localhost:8888 to mydomain.com.  I haven't quite made it work though, I'm still experiencing cookie blocking although my app and auth server are now on the same domain.

@HeikoTheißen My question relates to third-party cookies, not SameSite, which is related but not the same.  I believe the rules for third-party, and CORS, are different - a different port equals a different domain.

I was able to send a cookie to a different port even though my browser blocks third-party cookies.

Hmm, well, auth.mydomain.com and client.mydomain.com:8888 doesn't work for me, but maybe there's something else going on.  Thanks for your help.
